# Correct approach for immutable constructor injected Kotlin class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

What is the correct way to declare an immutable constructor injected class with Spring + Kotlin? Currently I have:

```
@RestController
public class AuthorizationController
{
    @Inject
    lateinit var facebookAuth: FacebookAuthorizationService //Mutable?

    @RequestMapping("/authorization")
    public fun authorization(@RequestParam(value = "network-type", defaultValue = "Facebook") name: String,
                             @RequestParam(value = "oauth-token") oauthToken: String,
                             @RequestParam(value = "oauth-token-secret",
                                     required = false) oauthTokenSecret: String?): Authorization
    {
        //TODO: Handle other network types
        return facebookAuth.authorization(oauthToken)
    }
}
```

I would like the facebookAuth property to be immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much experience with Kotlin here, but I think it must be done with

```
public class AuthorizationController @Inject constructor(private val facebookAuth: FacebookAuthorizationService) {

    ...

}
```